# c# WinForms - Showing hidden window from static reference

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have problem with passing references to my windows in WinForms project and then retrieving them.
I have Login form when I create another (Main) form and hidding Login form in button event(I don't want to destroy Login reference here so I keep it in static class) :

```
private void btnLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (CheckIfPasswordIsCorrect((int)DataSetUsers.Tables[0].Rows[cmbUsers.SelectedIndex][0]
                                            , txtPassword.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    GlobalData.LoginFormRef = this; //passing reference to Login form into static class
                    this.Hide(); //hidding Login form

                    MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
                    mainForm.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong password");
                    txtPassword.Focus();
                }
            }
```

GlobalData is static class with static object GlobalData.LoginFormRef so I can keep my Login form reference.

Then if I log out from my main form and want to back to login form I get an error or simply my application turns off :

```
private void btnLogOut_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
            {
                GlobalData.LoggedUser = null;

                if (GlobalData.LoginFormRef != null)
                {
                    GlobalData.LoginFormRef.Show(); //trying to show my login form back
                }

                this.Close(); //closing Main form
                this.Dispose(true); //destroying main form
            }
```

When I'm closing my Main form and trying to invoke Login form back it disappears immediately or I'm getting an error System.ObjectDisposedException . I don't understand why. I have my reference to Login form in static class .... How can I destroy main form and show again Login form ?

Comment: Sounds like the error is not where you expect it to be.  I think you'll need to show more of your code, like `GlobalData`, the classes where both your login/logout methods live, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe start your application by using `Application.Run(new MainForm())`?

If you did, then it registered the closing event for MainForm with an event handler that closes the UI thread.
This will dispose all the forms including your login form (and will exit the application assuming you don't have any living non background threads).

See the remarks in msdn for Application.Run(Form): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer but actually I started my application with `Application.Run(new Login)` so it's not a solution for me.

Comment: @DearDeer You are almost certainly closing the form used in `Application.Run` or disposing of it.